# Excel: Change alphanumeric values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula that will make the following changes to alphanumeric cells of variable length:

- Change alphabetic characters to Z
- Change numbers by incrementing 1 (9 becomes 0)

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | ZZZ234 |
| 1A2B3C | 2Z3Z4Z |
| 1A | 2Z |
| 99F | 00Z |

I can't use VBA in this application unfortunately.

I've tried combinations of SUBSTITUTE and REPLACE without success.
Thanks in advance if you have any suggestions or let me know if it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then the following formula should work as per the given conditions:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, --MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),
     CONCAT(IF(ISERR(--α), "Z", XLOOKUP(α, SEQUENCE(9)-1, SEQUENCE(9,,0)+1,0))))
```

---

- `α` split the string using `MID()` function.
- `--α` test whether its a number or text so for a number it will return `FALSE` while for a text it will return `TRUE`
- use `IF()` to completely change any alphabetic character to `Z` while for numbers doing an `XLOOKUP()` to return an incrementing number, while for the error which is `9` it returns `0`
- Lastly, using `CONCAT()` to combine all together into one piece.

---

The above is actually this but using `LET()` it makes easier to read and understand:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(XLOOKUP(--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),SEQUENCE(9)-1,SEQUENCE(9,,0)+1,0),"Z"))
```

---

Or, Single dynamic array formula to spill:

```
=BYROW(A2:A5,LAMBDA(α, CONCAT(IFERROR(
  XLOOKUP(--MID(α,SEQUENCE(LEN(α)),1),SEQUENCE(9)-1,SEQUENCE(9,,0)+1,0),"Z"))))
```

---

Bit shorter I think:

```
=LET(α,--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),CONCAT(IFERROR(IF(α=9,0,α+1),"Z")))
```

---

Comment: this is fantastic and successful. Thank you! Solved.

Comment: @lyall if that has worked then makesure to accept the answer by ticking the checkmark beside it so it helps someone in the future looking for a solution like yours and we can use the same to mark it as **duplicate**